# Android how can i fix the xml layout of my application to become like the dimensions of the mobile

Tags: android, xml, layout, size, screen

The mobile screen am working with is 5+" and the xml graphical layout editor is very small, so the problem that am facing here is when am placing the design on the xml graphical layout everything is looking good, but when debugging on the device the dimensions are all wrong.

How can i make the graphical layout editor the same size as my actual device, so that i wouldn't have to keep guessing what will work and what will not.

Comment: Post your XML. But, in general, don't use PX but DP.

Comment: i want to be able to see the design on the graphical layout, exactly like am going to see it on the device, regardless of the xml

Comment: Errr, what? The end result depends a lot on which components and Layout containers you are using, so something that looks well on the graphical design might not actually translate well to the real devices (It seems that you are just dragging components on to the design). The XML is really important, and the design view is mostly a preview and guide, but in the end you will need to master the XML anyway. Plus, we can't really tell you what you're doing wrong without the XML.

Answer (score 0):

At the top left of the layout editor, there's a dropdown with sizes and screen resolutions.  Select your device's screen size from that to preview it as if it were on that device.  You're likely looking for either `5.1in WGVA` or `5.4in FWVGA`.